# Pandas GroupBy using multiple columns and multiple indexes and convert to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a csv file as such (I removed the commas and all):

```
ID Team Col3 Col4 Value
3   t1   c2   x1   0.124
6   t2   c11  x10  1.342
7   t3   c5   x2   0.654
4   t3   c5   x2   123.3
5   t2   c11  x10  75.2
9   t2   c11  x10  34.97 
1   t1   c2   x1   0.23
```

I'm looking to group by Team, Col3, and Col4 and turn it into a dictionary whose values are ID and Value. So it looks like this

```
{
  (t1, c2, x1): [[3, 0.124],[1, 0.23]],
  (t2, c11, x10): [[6, 1.342], [5, 75.2], [9, 34.97]],
  (t3, c5, x2): [[7, 0.654], [4, 123.3]]
}
```

My code right now is

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
gk = dict(df.groupby(['team', 'Col3', 'Col4']).apply(list))
```

This code returns the keys how I want them (in tuple form), but the values of each key are simply just the column names... like such

```
(t1, c2, x1): ['ID', 'team', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Value']
```

How can I make it as such that the values of the dictionary are only the 'ID' and 'Value' columns?

Comment: try `dict(df.groupby(['team', 'Col3', 'Col4'])['ID','Value'].apply(list))`

Comment: Just tried it, instead of showing all the column names. Now it only shows 'ID' and 'Value'. Like this:
`(t1, c2, x1): ['ID', 'Value']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If integers in `ID` should be converted to floats use custom lambda function for convert both columns selected after groupby to numpy array, then to lists and last convert to dictioanry:

```
gk = (df.groupby(['Team', 'Col3', 'Col4'])[['ID','Value']]
        .apply(lambda x: x.to_numpy().tolist())
        .to_dict())
print (gk)
{('t1', 'c2', 'x1'): [[3.0, 0.124], [1.0, 0.23]], ('t2', 'c11', 'x10'): [[6.0, 1.3419999999999999], [5.0, 75.2], [9.0, 34.97]], ('t3', 'c5', 'x2'): [[7.0, 0.654], [4.0, 123.3]]}
```

Or use `zip` of both columns in custom function, then types are not changed:

```
gk = (df.groupby(['Team', 'Col3', 'Col4'])
        .apply(lambda x: list(zip(x['ID'], x['Value'])))
        .to_dict())
print (gk)
{('t1', 'c2', 'x1'): [(3, 0.124), (1, 0.23)], ('t2', 'c11', 'x10'): [(6, 1.3419999999999999), (5, 75.2), (9, 34.97)], ('t3', 'c5', 'x2'): [(7, 0.654), (4, 123.3)]}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. It won't let me accept the answer for another 7 minutes, but I will accept this one.